# python GUI closing one frame and opening another

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm writing a program that uses two classes (team class and league class) for a hockey team.  The GUI is simulating a single round elimination "playoffs" with 8 teams.  I want the GUI to allow the user to enter the scores for the first round of 4 games and then click the submit button.  When this button is pressed, I want a messagebox to pop up that lists the winners, and then when that box is closed, the original frame to close, and have the round 2 entry fields pop up.  I'm really unsure how to do this. 
I have a lot of code, so I haven't included the code for the team and league classes because I don't think it is necessary for this question, but I can post it if anyone wants.

So basically, is there a way to close on frame/ change the look of a frame to a new frame with the click of a button?

```
#methods to set the scores for round 1
def round1game1team1Score(self):
    """set the score for team 1"""
    team1= self.l.getTeambyPosition(0)
    teamScore= self.round1game1team1Var.get()
    team1.setScore(teamScore)

def round1game1team8Score(self):
    """sets the score for team 8"""
    team8= self.l.getTeambyPosition(7)
    teamScore= self.round1game1team8Var.get()
    team8.setScore(teamScore)

def round1game2team2Score(self):
    """sets the score for team 2"""
    team2= self.l.getTeambyPosition(1)
    teamScore= self.round1game2team2Var.get()
    team2.setScore(teamScore)

def round1game2team7Score(self):
    """sets the score for team 7"""
    team7= self.l.getTeambyPosition(6)
    teamScore= self.round1game2team7Var.get()
    team7.setScore(teamScore)

def round1game3team3Score(self):
    """sets the score for team 3"""
    team3= self.l.getTeambyPosition(2)
    teamScore= self.round1game3team3Var.get()
    team3.setScore(teamScore)

def round1game3team6Score(self):
    team6= self.l.getTeambyPosition(5)
    teamScore= self.round1game3team6Var.get()
    team6.setScore(teamScore)

def round1game4team4Score(self):
    """sets the score for team 4"""
    team4= self.l.getTeambyPosition(3)
    teamScore= self.round1game4team4Var.get()
    team4.setScore(teamScore)

def round1game4team5Score(self):
    """sets the score for team 5"""
    team5= self.l.getTeambyPosition(4)
    teamScore= self.round1game4team5Var.get()
    team5.setScore(teamScore)


#methods that determine the winners in round 1
def round1game1Winner(self):
    """determines the winner of round 1 game 1"""
    team1= self.l.getTeambyPosition(0)
    team8= self.l.getTeambyPosition(7)
    if team1.getScore() > team8.getScore():
        return team1.getTeam()
    else:
        return team8.getTeam()

def round1game2Winner(self):
    """determines the winner of round 1 game 2"""
    team2= self.l.getTeambyPosition(1)
    team7= self.l.getTeambyPosition(6)
    if team2.getScore() > team7.getScore():
        return team2.getTeam()
    else:
        return team7.getTeam()

def round1game3Winner(self):
    """determines the winner of round 1 game 3"""
    team3= self.l.getTeambyPosition(2)
    team6= self.l.getTeambyPosition(5)
    if team3.getScore() > team6.getScore():
        return team3.getTeam()
    else:
        return team6.getTeam()

def round1game4Winner(self):
    """determines the winner of round 1 game 4"""
    team4= self.l.getTeambyPosition(3)
    team5= self.l.getTeambyPosition(4)
    if team4.getScore() > team5.getScore():
        return team4.getTeam()
    else:
        return team5.getTeam()

def closeRound1Frame(self):
    """closes round1 frame"""
    self.Destroy()



class Round1Frame(Frame):
    """GUI for round1 of the playoffs"""
    def __init__(self):
        """sets up the window and widgets"""
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("2013 Stanley Cup Playoffs Round 1")
        self.grid()
        self.l= League()

        #round 1 game 1
        #team 1 label and entry field
        team1= self.l.getTeambyPosition(0).getTeam()
        round1game1team1Label= Label(self, text= str(team1) + '   ' + 'vs.' )
        round1game1team1Label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.round1game1team1Var = IntVar()
        round1game1team1Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round1game1team1Var)
        round1game1team1Entry.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        #team 8 label and entry field
        team8= self.l.getTeambyPosition(7).getTeam()
        round1game1team8Label= Label(self, text= str(team8))
        round1game1team8Label.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.round1game1team8Var= IntVar()
        round1game1team8Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round1game1team8Var)
        round1game1team8Entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


        #round 1 game 2
        #team 2 label and entry field
        team2= self.l.getTeambyPosition(1).getTeam()
        round1game2team2Label= Label(self, text= str(team2) + '   ' + 'vs.')
        round1game2team2Label.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        self.round1game2team2Var= IntVar()
        round1game2team2Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round1game2team2Var)
        round1game2team2Entry.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        #team 7 label and entry field
        team7= self.l.getTeambyPosition(6).getTeam()
        round1game2team7Label= Label(self, text= str(team7))
        round1game2team7Label.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
        self.round1game2team7Var= IntVar()
        round1game2team7Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round1game2team7Var)
        round1game2team7Entry.grid(row = 1, column = 3)


        #round 1 game 3
        #team 3 label and entry field
        team3= self.l.getTeambyPosition(2).getTeam()
        round1game3team3Label= Label(self, text= str(team3) + '   ' + 'vs.')
        round1game3team3Label.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.round1game3team3Var= IntVar()
        round1game3team3Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round1game3team3Var)
        round1game3team3Entry.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

        #team 6 label and entry field
        team6= self.l.getTeambyPosition(5).getTeam()
        round1game3team6Label= Label(self, text= str(team6))
        round1game3team6Label.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.round1game3team6Var= IntVar()
        round1game3team6Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round1game3team6Var)
        round1game3team6Entry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)


        #round 1 game 4
        #team 4 label and entry field
        team4= self.l.getTeambyPosition(3).getTeam()
        round1game4team4Label= Label(self, text= str(team4) + '   ' + 'vs.')
        round1game4team4Label.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        self.round1game4team4Var= IntVar()
        round1game4team4Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round1game4team4Var)
        round1game4team4Entry.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

        #team 5 label and field entry
        team5= self.l.getTeambyPosition(4).getTeam()
        round1game4team5Label= Label(self, text= str(team5))
        round1game4team5Label.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
        self.round1game4team5Var= IntVar()
        round1game4team5Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round1game4team5Var)
        round1game4team5Entry.grid(row = 3, column =3)

        #button to submit round 1 scores
        round1Button= Button(self, text= 'Submit Scores', command= self.round1)
        round1Button.grid(row = 4, column = 1, columnspan = 2)



    def round1(self):
        """event handler for the round1Button"""
        round1game1team1Score(self)
        round1game1team8Score(self)
        round1game2team2Score(self)
        round1game2team7Score(self)
        round1game3team3Score(self)
        round1game3team6Score(self)
        round1game4team4Score(self)
        round1game4team5Score(self)
        round1game1Winner(self)
        round1game2Winner(self)
        round1game3Winner(self)
        round1game4Winner(self)
        messagebox.showinfo(title= 'Round 1 Results',
                            message= 'Winners advancing to next round: ' + '\n' + str(round1game1Winner(self))
                            + '\n' + str(round1game2Winner(self)) + '\n' +
                            str(round1game3Winner(self)) + '\n' +
                            str(round1game4Winner(self)))
        closeRound1Frame(self)
        Round2Frame().mainloop()

class Round2Frame(Frame):
    """GUI for round 2 of the playoffs"""
    def __int__(self):
        """sets up the window and widgets"""
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title('2013 Stanley Cup Playoffs Round 2')
        self.grid()

        #round 2 game 1
        #first team label and entry field
        team1= round1game1Winner(self)
        round2game1team1Label= Label(self, text= str(team1) + 'vs.   ')
        round2game1team1Label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.round2game1team1Var= IntVar()
        round2game1team1Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round2game1team1Var)
        round2game1team1Entry.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        #second team label and entry field
        team2= round1game2Winner(self)
        round2game1team2Label= Label(self, text= str(team2))
        round2game1team2Label.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.round2game1team2Var= IntVar()
        round2game1team2Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round2game1team2Var)
        round2game1team2Entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


        #round 2 game 2
        #third team label and entry field
        team3= round1game3Winner(self)
        round2game2team3Label= Label(self, text= str(team3) + 'vs.   ')
        round2game2team3Label.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        self.round2game2team3Var= IntVar()
        round2game2team3Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round2game2team3Var)
        round2game2team3Entry.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        #fourth team label and entry field
        team4= round1game4Winner(self)
        round2game2team4Label= Label(self, text= str(team4))
        round2game2team4Label.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
        self.round2game2team4Var= IntVar()
        round2game2team4Entry= Entry(self,
                                     textvariable= self.round2game2team4Var)
        round2game2team4Entry.grif(row = 1, column = 3)




def main():
    """instantiate and pop up the window"""
    Round1Frame().mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: When you use the word "frame" in your question, are you referring to an instance of the `Frame` class, or a complete window like you get when you create an instance of `Tk` or `Toplevel`?

Comment: @BryanOakley: I'm not sure what tk or toplevel are so I've been trying to look them up.  Would you recommend using them in this situation, or is it possible to actually close an instance of the Frame class and instantiate a new Frame?

Comment: you must create an instance of `Tk` for your app to work. If you're not, one will be created for you. There must always be one and only one. Nearly all Tkinter apps start by creating an instance of `Tk`. If they need additional windows they create instances of `Toplevel`. `mainloop` is usually called on the original instance of `Tk`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank, but I am still a little confused.  Is what I have now sufficient if I just change the round 2 class to a TopLevel window? Or do I have to change my original Frame as well? Some of the online tutorials online have mentioned things like root and I'm not really sure how to use that/ if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to change the way a frame looks at the click of a button. Any attribute you can set when you create a frame (`borderwidth`, `background`, etc) can be set at any time using the `configure` method:

```
import Tkinter as tk
...
f = tk.Frame(..., background="green", ...)
...
f.configure(background="red")
...
```

As for "closing" a frame -- frames can't be "closed" per se, but you can delete them with the `destroy` method. This will destroy the frame and all of its child widgets:

```
f.destroy()
```

Comment: but you wouldn't be able to change the widgets within the frame is that right?